# scale to fit/fill image as pointStyle in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

is there a way to scale image to fit/fill in chartjs, image as pointStyle on chart, we can load an image but cant set it as fill or fit, we can only provide width, height to that image.

we can use image as pointStyle for a datapoint in line chart by sending an image object to the array of pointStyle in the dataset, in the image object we can only send height and width for the image to render on the point,
my specific question is how can we scale image to fit or fill upon sending it to the pointStyle array to render as datapoint?

lets say i have a picture original at 200x200
we create an Image object of 100x100,
can we specify the image to fit or fill that 100x100 we specified above as the image object.

the expected result should be like we can do in css “object-fit:fill” property on HTML
hope the question is more clear now.

Comment: If I understood well, you could try to use a CanvasPattern based on your image (for filling)

Comment: @user2057925 what do you mean by that? could you elaborate ?

Comment: This question needs more clarification. I'm voting to leave it open, but please add more details, perhaps even some sample code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @amihai it's still not clear to me if you need to add an image to fill a dataset or if the image must be set as background or something different. To fill a dataset you can do it by a color (string), CanvasGradient or CanvasPattern. Let me know what you need to do it, then I'll do my best to provide you a sample

Comment: we can set a point as image using pointStyle attribute on a dataset, can we in any way set the image as scale to fit or fill on that pointStyle ? asfik we can only set new Image with width & height.

Comment: Chartjs uses the width and height of the image or canvas element, passed as pointStyle, to draw on the canvas. https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/0edb2ac604a4a93bcddfdaefc112bf4bd73b21fa/src/helpers/helpers.canvas.js#L146

Comment: @user2057925 that means we can create a new canvas and scale to fill/fit image on it and assign it as pointStyle ??

Comment: Yes, but didn't test it

Comment: update: the way @user2057925  suggested is working, will share code shortly